# Azure SQL Database: load json file from Azure storage

Tags: sql, azure-storage, azure-sql-database

I was wondering if it's possible to load a json file stored in an Azure storage account (blob or file share) directly from Azure SQL Database to then leverage the new openjson syntax.

I tried following command in my Azure SQL Database:

```
Select * from openrowset(bulk '\\mystorage.file.core.windows.net\myshare\myfile.json', single_clob) as jsondata
```

but it throws me an error "You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement".

After googling around I couldn't find anything which could help me on the way.

Is it even possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPENROWSET(BULK) and BULK INSERT T-SQL statements are not yet enabled in Azure SQL Database. You can use them in SQL server on-prem to load files from Azure Blob Storage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt805207.aspx

I cannot confirm exact date when these statements will be be enabled in Azure SQL Database (but trust me they will be available **very soon** :) ) and you will be able to load files from Azure Blob Storage.

Stay tuned and keep monitoring [Azure service updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt805207.aspx) :)